# Can Flexbox help me?

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I have inherited somebody else's problem. The HTML is all DIVs with floats, displays and positioning tweaks. The one thing I cannot change is the structured of the HTML DIVs. Nor do I wish to add any new javascript libraries. But I can add all the CSS I need to the existing DIVs.

Currently 3 DIVs are embedded as:

```html
<DIV id="firstrow"> 1 </DIV>
<DIV id="secondrow">
    <DIV> 2 </DIV>
    <DIV> 3 </DIV>
</DIV>
```

Take a look at the graphic below. The problem with this is that as DIV1 grows down, the DIV3 gets bumped down. I wish to keep DIV3 fully justified from the top to bottom (as if STRETCH).

Without getting into how the current code combines DISPLAYS, FLOATS, and POSITIONING -- I think I need to erase all the CSS and replace with some FLEXBOX. But I cannot seem to get the right combination of FLEX properties to make DIV3 behave to stretch (instead of getting bumped down).

Fortunately, this only has to work for Chrome on Desktop (no mobile nor other browsers).

[image: DIV rows]

Comment: can you change your html structure?  If so I would swap it so 1 and 2 are together and 3 is on it's own, then flex can help - https://jsfiddle.net/k9bjdf34/4

Comment: I wish I could. Unfortunately, I cannot. It's complicated but basically there are some outside scripts that needs to read the HTML structure as is. I can only add CSS to the existing HTLM structure.

Comment: then you cannot do it with your current html

Comment: Using @Pete solution and some javascript to manipulate the HTML structure?

Comment: I can add some javascript, but I am only a novice at that. I will add the javascript tag to this post and see if I get some answers. Thanks.

Comment: ok if you can put a wrapper around your above html and column3 will never be taller than 1 and 2 combined, then you can use a dirty absolute positioning hack (but only if secondrow is position:static):  https://jsfiddle.net/k9bjdf34/9/

Comment: *"Can Flexbox help me?"* - NO...it can't

Comment: Are firstrow and secondrow the only children of a common parent ? Add this in the example also

Comment: Thanks @Pete! You and August were both correct. These work for me. Next time, don't be so quick to say, 'no.'

Comment: The answers don't use your current html - they add a wrapper, so my comment is still true - it cannot be done with your current html alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There you go IF width of div 3 is known and fixed value:
https://codepen.io/AugustinF/pen/qYBpmR

```
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
}
#firstrow {
  height: 100px;
  margin-right: 200px;
  background: green;

}
#secondrow {
}
#div2 {
  float:left;
  background: blue;
}
#div3 {
  width: 200px;
  position: absolute;
  top:0;
  right:0;
  height: 100%;
  background: red;
}
.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper clearfix">
    <DIV id="firstrow"> 1 </DIV>
    <DIV id="secondrow clearfix">
        <DIV id="div2"> 2 </DIV>
        <DIV id="div3"> 3 </DIV>
    </DIV>
</div>
```

Using @Pete solution you can modify the HTML structure using javascript by placing this code at the end of the body tag:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('firstrow').appendChild(
    document.getElementById('div2')
  );
</script>
```